# QLineEdit в центре QGridLayout ячейки

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Имеется такой код. Создается массив фреймов и массив `QLineEdit`. Я добавляю `QLineEdit` во фрейм с помощью `setParent`. Выводиться не так как надо. Надо чтобы `QLineEdit` был в центре фрейма.

А как это сделать?

```
frame = new QFrame[22];
for ( int i = 0; i < 22; i++ ) {
    frame[i].setParent(this);
    frame[i].setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box | QFrame::Sunken);
    frame[i].setLineWidth(4);

}

line = new QLineEdit[22];
for ( int i = 0; i < 22; i++ ) {
    line[i].setParent(&frame[i]);
    line[i].setFixedWidth(20);

}
```

Comment: чем вы руководствовались, используя `setParent`?

Comment: @magrif ну я создаю массив qframe, а когда создаешь массив, нельзя присвоить родителя. Вот я потом и присваиваю родителя, чтобы отдельным виджетом не открылась.

Comment: Как на счет компоновок?

Comment: @magrif А как это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаём на интерфейсе пустой `QWidget` с именем `wgt` нужного размера, где будут размещаться наши фреймы.

```
QGridLayout* glo = new QGridLayout(ui->wgt);  //сетчатая компоновка
glo->setSpacing(3); //отступы между фреймами
for(auto i = 0 ; i<10 ; ++i) {
    for(auto j = 0 ; j<10 ; ++j) {
        QFrame* frame = new QFrame(ui->wgt); //фрейм
        frame->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box | QFrame::Sunken); 
        QLineEdit* le = new QLineEdit(frame); //лайнедит
        QHBoxLayout* lo = new QHBoxLayout(frame);  //компоновка по горизонтали, 
        lo->setSpacing(0); 
        lo->setMargin(0);
        lo->addWidget(le); //в которую помещаем виджет le
        frame->setLayout(lo); //компоновку устанавливаем на фрейм 
        glo->addWidget(frame, i, j); //который добавляем в сетчатую компоновку
    }
}
//устанавливаем сетчатую компоновку на наш пустой виджет 
ui->wgt->setLayout(glo);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ух ты спасибо.!